# How to self-redirect and changing a parameter in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If my urls looks like:
www.mysite.com/1/home
www.mysite.com/1/other-action
www.mysite.com/1/another-action/?value=a

how can I switch the 1 parameter while invoking the same action with the same parameters and querystring values?

For example if I'm currently browsing
www.mysite.com/1/another-action/?value=a
I would like to obtain the necessary links to switch to
www.mysite.com/2/another-action/?value=a
.
.
www.mysite.com/x/another-action/?value=a

Url.Action seems not to help...

Answer (score 3):

The general idea is clone the current RouteValueDictionary, change one value, and then build a new action link based on the new RouteValueDictionary. Here's an example. But you'd probably want to do this in a URL helper, rather than directly in the view:

```
    <% var foo = new RouteValueDictionary();
       foreach (var value in ViewContext.RouteData.Values)
       {
           foo.Add(value.Key, value.Value);
       }
       foo["id"] = 2;
       var newUrl = Url.Action(foo["action"].ToString(), foo); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose small optimization to Craig's answer:

`<% var foo = new RouteValueDictionary(ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
   foo["id"] = 2;
   var newUrl = Url.Action(foo["action"].ToString(), foo); %>`